# How to calculate the power of equipments connected to a voltage regulator?

Tags: voltage, power, current, voltage-regulator, safety

I have a voltage regulator just like this, I do not know how to use it, so, I wonder if there is a way to calculate the capacity of equipments which I connect to it so that they don't exceed its capacity?

[image: Pic of a twin of my voltage regulator]

Also, I wanted to know what would happen if the equipments connected was more than its capacity?

And more important is it possible to connect more than one equipment by using a multi-socket?

Comment: To be sure I'd need more information like the model number so I can find its manual. But, I would assume it has a transformer output and that the 500VA rating applied to either output provided you only used one. The VA rating being the rated voltage of your equipment 220 or 110V multiplied by the rated current.  If this is less than 500VA you can use this regulator.

Comment: It says right there on the front that this is Model ST500 rated at 500VA. So if the 220V output was used the load cannot exceed 500VA/220V=2.27A.

Comment: Contact the supplier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equipment you connect should be marked as to the VA. Add them all up and they should be less than the 500VA that device is capable of. There might also be problems if some equipment draws large surges, for example when starting.

There is **no problem** running many devices from the output- only the total consumption matters.

If you overload it it may overheat, the fuse may blow or it may fail early. If it's badly made it might emit dangerous fumes or present a fire hazard.

The device appears to be a servomotor-driven variable auto-transformer (Variac) so it will take some time to adjust for mains variations (maybe a second or two). Whatever is connected must be able to withstand a surge or brown-out of that duration without damage.